# Request app deletion for a given user handle

Tags: android

Normally I do uninstall apps like following:

```
fun uninstall(context: Context, packageName: String, userHandle: UserHandle) {
    // userHandle is unused currently
    context.startActivity(
        Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE).apply {
            data = Uri.parse("package:$packageName")
        }.apply {
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        }
    )
}
```

When starting an activity as a user I use the `LAUNCHER_APPS_SERVICE` but it does not offer a function for requesting an app uninstall.

**Question**

How can I request to uninstall an app for a given user? (I don't want a silent delete, I just want to open the delete popup)

Answer (score 0):

It's not documented, but following works - simple add `Intent.EXTRA_USER`:

```
fun uninstall(context: Context, userHandle: UserHandle, packageName: String) : Boolean{
    return context.startActivity(
        Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE).apply {
            data = Uri.parse("package:$packageName")
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_USER, userHandle)
        }.apply {
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        }
    )
}
```